# sql query: how to filter records on table by applying where condition on a top record from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get records from Leads table by applying where condition(e.g when  LSH.status=5) should apply on only on top first record(i made `LSH.leads_status_id DESC`) from table `leads_status_history`, how to filter the records ?
But currently by using below sql query it filters (i.e where LSH.status=5) it filter out all records with this condition . I want to filter only on latest single record

Here is Expected output explanation

Case1: When LSH.status=5, (because with status=5 it is latest record)

**expected Output:**

```
leads_name
---------
Ritaz Texttile
```

---

### Case 2: When LSH.status=1,
**expected Output:**

0 record (Because its old record, no matched)

### Case 3: When LSH.status=2,
**expected Output:**

0 record (Because its old record, no matched)

### Case 4: When LSH.status=3,
**expected Output:**

0 record (Because no matched,no records in database)

Query I tried for example for case 1

```
select L.leads_name
    from leads L LEFT JOIN leads_user_relation LUR ON LUR.leads_id_fk=L.leads_id 
    LEFT JOIN leads_status_history LSH ON LUR.leads_user_relation_id=LSH.leads_user_relation_id_fk 
    WHERE   LUR.leads_id_fk IS NOT NULL 
    AND (LSH.leads_user_relation_id_fk is NOT null AND LSH.status=5)
    AND LUR.user_id_fk =1 GROUP BY L.leads_id ORDER BY LSH.leads_status_id DESC
```

SQL Fiddle you can try here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7e081/4

Table Relations:
[image]

Comment: Are you able to understand my question! Let me know if you have any query, i will quickly reply

Comment: what is the reason for -ve vote! Please write the reason so i can know and learn for -ve vote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [following](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/79V38uo4PgvX7ogRUacPmA/0):

```
WITH LatestStatus AS (
  SELECT
    LSH.leads_user_relation_id_fk,
    LSH.status,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LSH.leads_user_relation_id_fk ORDER BY LSH.leads_status_id DESC) AS rn
  FROM
    leads_status_history LSH
)
select  L.leads_name
from leads L 
LEFT JOIN leads_user_relation LUR 
  ON LUR.leads_id_fk=L.leads_id 
LEFT JOIN LatestStatus LSH 
  ON LUR.leads_user_relation_id=LSH.leads_user_relation_id_fk 
WHERE LUR.leads_id_fk IS NOT NULL 
  AND 
  (
      LSH.leads_user_relation_id_fk is NOT null 
      AND LSH.status = 5
      AND LSH.rn = 1
  )
  AND LUR.user_id_fk = 1
```

The idea is to first order the records from your history table and get only the first one (with the highest status).

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SELECT L.leads_name
FROM leads L 
LEFT JOIN leads_user_relation LUR ON LUR.leads_id_fk=L.leads_id 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT status, leads_status_id, leads_user_relation_id_fk
    FROM  leads_status_history 
    ORDER BY leads_status_id DESC limit 1) LSH ON LUR.leads_user_relation_id = LSH.leads_user_relation_id_fk 
WHERE   LUR.leads_id_fk IS NOT NULL 
AND (LSH.leads_user_relation_id_fk is NOT null AND LSH.status=5)
AND LUR.user_id_fk =1 GROUP BY L.leads_id ORDER BY LSH.leads_status_id DESC
```